# Post DocuSign Envelope with base64 string failed for non-pdf file

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to post an envelope but it keeps failing for non-pdf file with   the following failure:

```
<errorCode>UNABLE_TO_LOAD_DOCUMENT</errorCode>
   <message>Unable to load the document. Unable to load Document(1;Parking Application). Error: the document is corrupt, rebuilding failed </message>
```

I know that I can trying sending the document as multi-part request but I'm wondering what is the issue in this request:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4IcppTb9svVSFhXYkdFa0gtbms/view
it contains a word document. 
It doesn't seem to be an issue with the base64 encoded string because the string can be decoded back to the file just fine e.g. using http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the

```
      <fileExtension>docx</fileExtension>
```

node in your XML adjacent to the `documentBase64` node.

(The snippet above assumes you're sending a docx file. Change it to whatever the filetype is.)

In other words, if your document is not a pdf, you need to tell the platform what the format of your documents are. It assumes pdf.

Comment: Thanks Larry, this was exactly the issue.